# How to get combined coverage on both unit test and integration test using NYC

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, istanbul, nyc

I want to get a combined coverage of both unit-test and integration-test.

I have seperate folders for both unit-test and integration-test. In my pipeline ci i have a seperate stage for unit-test and integration-test becasue the integration-test requires a dependency.

**package.json**

```
{
 "unit-test": "nyc mocha --timeout 5000000 -r ts-node/register --project tsconfig.json test/unit/*.test.ts --exit",
 "integration-test": "nyc mocha --timeout 5000000 -r ts-node/register --project tsconfig.json test/integration/*.test.ts --exit",
}
```

Right now i get coverage report for both of them seperatly, but what i can see is that its not a true reflection of all the coverage.

Is there someway i can combine the coverage summary. It might mean that i would need to combine the 2 stages in my pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

There is a **nyc** `merge` feature, that is able to merge multiple coverage reports that are produced by different test runs. You can read about it in the [**nyc** docs](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc#combining-reports-from-multiple-runs).

Other way is to run both tests in same command (as **mocha** is able to handle multiple input paths), like following:

```
"test": "nyc mocha --timeout 5000000 -r ts-node/register --project tsconfig.json 'test/unit/*.test.ts' 'test/integration/*.test.ts' --exit"
```